# for Loop commands - which is faster?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, for-loop

Consider the following code:

```
        int max = 1000;
        int min = 0;

        // Code sample A
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] < min) min = array[i];
            else if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
        }
```

and,

```
        // Code Sample B
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] < min) min = array[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
        }
```

Of the above two code samples which one is more efficient?

I know some people would say that the first code sample would be faster as it does two instructions in one iteration. while, the second does it in two separate for loops. I am not so sure if that is true. Please explain.

Comment: Why don't you just profile it?

Comment: I am fairly new in programming. Could you tell me how its done please.

Comment: Some has tagged your question as C#. Are you using C#? Might as well be Java...

Comment: My bad. Removing the language tag.

Comment: I did copy the code from a c# compiler.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Btw, Why did I get so many down votes? Is it because this question is stupid?

Comment: More or less. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also this is more like a code review.

Comment: (Note that your code uses four comparisons where three would do: compare elements at _i_ and _i+1, smaller to `min` and greater to `max`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it simple,

**in case A,**

- your program has to initialize `i` only once.
- Assign values to `i` only `array.Length` times.
- Increase `i` values only `array.Length` times.
- do the line execution and comparison 2*`array.Length` times.

**In case B,**

- initialize `i` twice.
- Assign values to `i` 2*`array.Length` times.
- Increase `i` values 2*`array.Length` times.
- do line execution and comparison 2*`array.Length` times.

So, which one you would prefer?

Answer (score 0):

Prajwal's answer is pretty accurate.
It is not difficult to test this (in Java):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int max = 1000;
    int min = 0;
    long start, stop, diff;

    int[] arr = new int[100_000];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = (int) (-500_000 + Math.random() * 1_000_000);

    start = System.nanoTime();

    // Code sample A
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];

        else if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }

    stop = System.nanoTime();
    diff = stop - start;
    System.out.println("nanoseconds needed for A: " + diff);

    min = 0; max = 1000;

    start = System.nanoTime();

    // Code Sample B
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }

    stop = System.nanoTime();
    diff = stop - start;
    System.out.println("nanoseconds needed for B: " + diff);

}
```

The result of it:

```
nanoseconds needed for A: 563581
nanoseconds needed for B: 1018710
```